# Perl Mismatch among arrays

Tags: perl

I have two arrays:

```
@array1 = (A,B,C,D,E,F);
@array2 = (A,C,H,D,E,G);
```

The arrays could be of different size. I want to find how many mismatches are there between the arrays. The indexes should be the same. In this case there are three mismatch :`b->c`,`c->h` and `F->G`.(i.e , The '`C`' in `$array[2]` should not be considered a match to '`C`' in `$array[1]`) I would like to get the number of mismatches as well as the mismatch.

```
foreach my $a1 ( 0 .. $#array1) {
 foreach my $a2( 0 .. $#array2)
  if($array1[$a1] ne $array2[$a2]) {

   }
 }
}

my %array_one = map {$_, 1} @array1;
my @difference = grep {!$array_one {$_}} @array1;

print "@difference\n";
```

Ans: gives me `H`, `G` but not `C`.

with my little Perl knowledge I tried this, with no result. Could you suggest me how I should deal this? Your suggestions and pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: Don't you want to use the same index for each one?

Comment: Sorry , I am not understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [`each_arrayref`](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) from [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMoreUtils).

```
sub diff_array{
  use List::MoreUtils qw'each_arrayref';
  return unless @_ && defined wantarray;
  my @out;

  my $iter = each_arrayref(@_);

  my $index = 0;
  while( my @current = $iter->() ){
    next if all_same(@current);

    unshift @current, $index;
    push @out, \@current;
  }continue{ ++$index }

  return @out;
}
```

This version should be faster if you are going to use this for determining the number of differences often. The output is exactly the same. It just doesn't have to work as hard when returning a number.
<sup><sub>Read about [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) for more information.</sub></sup>

```
sub diff_array{
  use List::MoreUtils qw'each_arrayref';
  return unless @_ && defined wantarray;

  my $iter = each_arrayref(@_);

  if( wantarray ){
    # return structure
    my @out;

    my $index = 0;
    while( my @current = $iter->() ){
      next if all_same(@current);

      unshift @current, $index;
      push @out, \@current;
    }continue{ ++$index }

    return @out;

  }else{
    # only return a count of differences
    my $out = 0;
    while( my @current = $iter->() ){
      ++$out unless all_same @current;
    }
    return $out;
  }
}
```

---

`diff_array` uses the subroutine `all_same` to determine if all of the current list of elements are the same.

```
sub all_same{
  my $head = shift;
  return undef unless @_; # not enough arguments
  for( @_ ){
    return 0 if $_ ne $head; # at least one mismatch
  }
  return 1; # all are the same
}
```

---

To get just the number of differences:

```
print scalar diff_array \@array1, \@array2;
my $count  = diff_array \@array1, \@array2;
```

To get a list of differences:

```
my @list = diff_array \@array1, \@array2;
```

To get both:

```
my $count = my @list = diff_array \@array1, \@array2;
```

The output for the input you provided:

```
(
  [ 1, 'B', 'C' ],
  [ 2, 'C', 'H' ],
  [ 5, 'F', 'G' ]
)
```

---

Example usage

```
my @a1 = qw'A B C D E F';
my @a2 = qw'A C H D E G';

my $count = my @list = diff_array \@a1, \@a2;

print "There were $count differences\n\n";

for my $group (@list){
  my $index = shift @$group;
  print "  At index $index\n";
  print "    $_\n" for @$group;
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks every one. I used Array::Each module to get the same index compared. And it worked fine too. Thanks every one for their time. I have learnt many other new ways too.

Comment: @SipraMoon [Array::Each](http://p3rl.org/Array::Each) is going to be noticeably slower than [each_arrayref](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils) (assuming that that the XS has been compiled).

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have nested loops. You only need to go through the indexes once.

```
use List::Util qw( max );

my @mismatches;
for my $i (0..max($#array1, $#array2)) {
   push @mismatches, $i
      if $i >= @array1
      || $i >= @array2
      || $array1[$i] ne $array2[$i];
   }
}

say "There are " . (0+@mismatches) . " mismatches";
for my $i (@mismatches) {
   ...
}
```

Since you mentioned `grep`, this is how you'd replace the `for` with `grep`:

```
use List::Util qw( max );

my @mismatches =
    grep {  $_ >= @array1
         || $_ >= @array2
         || array1[$_] ne $array2[$_] }
    0 .. max($#array1, $#array2);

say "There are " . (0+@mismatches) . " mismatches";
for my $i (@mismatches) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Sipra Moon, I missed that you want the actual mismatch. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over both arrays when you don't want to be doing so.

```
@array1 = ("A","B","C","D","E","F");
@array2 = ("A","C","H","D","E","G");
foreach my $index (0 .. $#array1) {
   if ($array1[$index] ne $array2[$index]) {
       print "Arrays differ at index $index: $array1[$index] and $array2[$index]\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Arrays differ at index 1: B and C
Arrays differ at index 2: C and H
Arrays differ at index 5: F and G
```

Comment: OP specified arrays can be different sizes. You're just ignoring the case where array2 is longer than array1.

Comment: That's true, and I was going to add that as a caveat.

Answer (score 1):

The following code builds a list of mismatched pairs, then prints them out.

```
@a1 = (A,B,C,D,E,F);
@a2 = (A,C,H,D,E,G);
@diff = map { [$a1[$_] => $a2[$_]] }
            grep { $a1[$_] ne $a2[$_] }
                 (0..($#a1 < $#a2 ? $#a1 : $#a2));
print "$_->[0]->$_->[1]\n" for @diff
```

Comment: That won't work so well if the arrays are a different length, and some of the elements are equal to undef (e.g., empty string). Or if a2 is longer than a2 (undef-equivalent or not). OP specified different lengths.

Comment: @derobert: I've amended my answer for the length issue. I don't understand your point about undef, though; the OP didn't indicate such a possibility and the original code worked fine if I set one of the list elements to the empty string. Of course, you can't do this in the list assignment, but I didn't consider that part of the problem proper.

Comment: First, I've fixed a typo in your ternary operator. Second, the undef issue is consider the arrays `@a1 = ('a', undef, 'c'); @a2 = ('a', '', 'c', '')`. Your code says there are no mismatches; but I think someone would expect there to be two mismatches. Perl considers `'' eq undef` to be true. The undef in the middle might be understandable (that is how eq is defined, after all), but the extra empty-string element going unnoticed is quite surprising to a user of your code, I think.

Comment: @derobert: Thanks for correcting the silly typo. As for the point about undefs, I get it, but that's just a quirk of `ne`. It's hardly up to me to say whether `undef` and `''`should be considered a match, especially since Perl itself says they are.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you're going to want to go over each element of one of the arrays, and compare it to the same element of the other array. List::MoreUtils provides an easy way to do this:

```
use v5.14;
use List::MoreUtils qw(each_array);

my @a = qw(a b c d);
my @b = qw(1 2 3);

my $ea = each_array @a, @b;
while ( my ($a, $b) = $ea->() ) {
    say "a = $a, b = $b, idx = ", $ea->('index');
}
```

You can extend that to find where there is a non-match by checking inside that while loop (note: this assumes your arrays don't have undefs at the end, or that if they do, undef is the same as having a shorter array):

```
my @mismatch;
my $ea = each_array @a, @b;
while ( my ($a, $b) = $ea->() ) {
    if (defined $a != defined $b || $a ne $b) {
        push @mismatch, $ea->('index');
    }
}
```

and then:

```
say "Mismatched count = ", scalar(@mismatch), " items are: ", join(q{, }, @mismatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but you only need a single loop, since you are looking at each index and comparing entries between the arrays:

```
foreach my $a1 ( 0 .. $#array1) {
  if($array1[$a1] ne $array2[$a1]) {
     print "$a1: $array1[$a1] <-> $array2[$a1]\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: OP specified arrays can be different sizes. You're just ignoring the case where array2 is longer than array1.